# Respond.js crossdomain proxy not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, proxy, cdn, respond.js

I am currently setting up respond.js with the proxy bundle because my website is running on a domain, and my css file are on the same server but not the same subdomain.

Here is my header:

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= STK_CDN_SERVER; ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= STK_CDN_SERVER; ?>/css/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= STK_CDN_SERVER; ?>/css/slick-theme.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?= STK_CDN_SERVER; ?>/css/app.css" media="all" />

<!-- FONTS -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- JS -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= STK_CDN_SERVER; ?>/js/respond.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.4.1/slick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?= STK_CDN_SERVER; ?>/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?= STK_CDN_SERVER; ?>/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- respond JS -->
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<!-- Respond JS proxy -->
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy">
<link href="/vendor/respondjs/respond.proxy.gif" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect">
<script src="/vendor/respondjs/respond.proxy.js"></script>
```

So the respond-proxy.html and respond.min.js are hosted by a CDN.
The respond.proxy.gif, respond.proxy.js are hosted on the "local" domain name.
And the other file are on another subdomain.

I did a lot of tests, lot of research about this but it still doesn't work..

Can somehelp help me please ?

Regards,

Comment: does the above markup work if you explicitly hardcoded the URL of the CDN? Just to test

Answer (score 0):

Your file **respond-proxy.html** must be hosted in the same domain as your bootstrap CSS.

So you have to upload the file to server.

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= STK_CDN_SERVER; ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Respond JS proxy -->
<link href="<?= STK_CDN_SERVER; ?>/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy">
```

This should work =)